# Omxplayer play duration

Tags: omxplayer

The `Omxplayer -s` repeatedly shows the elapsed time of the playing video (on the command line), showing the final duration when the video ends. How can I assign those times to a variable?

Comment: If you can use Python the omxplayer wrapper is very good https://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks Mike. I haven't yet progressed to Python, the multi-choice video player triggered by gpio inputs I made runs as a bash file. Is there no way to use bash commands, or is Python the only choice (I was hoping to avoid it) ?